# Subquery returned more than 1 value in update set clause

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, ado.net

I have two tables:

```
1-shipment_order_product(orderid,productid,quantity)
2-stock_product(productid,quantity)
```

In shipment_order_product table there are multiple `productid` against one `orderid` which means in one order i purchase multiple products.

I want to update the `stock_product` quantity of every `productid` i purchase against specific orderid.

Here is my query :

```
update product 
SET NoOfItems= (select sum(b.Quantity) 
from product as a,shippment_order_product as b
where a.Product_ID=b.Product_ID
group by a.Product_ID,b.Product_ID)
```

this gives error :

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

this is mssql - you tag as multiple

```
update p  
SET p.NoOfItems = sum(s.Quantity) 
from product as p 
join shippment_order_product as s
on p.Product_ID = s.Product_ID
group by p.Product_ID
```